# The <img> element doesn't show images html

Tags: html, css

i tried it in all my html projects and all images in my project are gone.Im sure the pictures path is correct.ı checked it too many times.here is my code.I didnt add css because there is nothing important;

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mad.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="C:\Users\Samet\Desktop\Resim\mogus.png">
    <title>wutr</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/K2D">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>There is 7 rules in this world</h1>
    <ol>
              <div class="prf"><li><p>There is only one thing in this world</p> </div></li>
    </ol>
    <img src="C:\Users\Samet\Desktop\Resim\mogus.png" alt="imgd" height="1000px"width="100px">
<p class="pain">Pain</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't show files from `c:\path` (or any other local directory) You need to serve them from a server or use relative paths from within the html file (e.g. `src="images/mogus.png"` )

Comment: It will work if browsing to `c:/path/index.html` eq `file://c:/path/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

You should refrain from using image paths such as this one however to make this work you can do the following

```
<img src="file://C:\Users\Samet\Desktop\Resim\mogus.png" alt="imgd" height="1000px"width="100px">
```

Keep in mind that this only works on Windows local machines. To select the file path from root on macOS or Linux operating systems you can simply use the following

```
<img src="/Users/Samet/Desktop/Resim/mogus.png" alt="imgd" height="1000px"width="100px">
```

After further reading into your question, another possible fix is to select the image path from the index.html location. So if your image is in the same directory as your HTML file you simply use `src="mogus.png"`

I hope this answered your question. If it didn't let me know and I will look into it further.

Answer (score -2):

there is nothing error here. please check your image format it's really in png format and also check your image is not corrupted. if the problem is not solved, kindly then attach your image here.

Comment: i checked format type and image path already and its correct.While the same pictures were showing before, none of them are visible now. I didn't change anything.

Comment: It's not working because you're using image path instead of url. You need to copy your images into your project for example in img folder and link it with your html code (your-project-folder/img/your-picture.png).

Comment: If you browse to your html file with for example C:/path/index.html , then you can use C:/path/image.jpg (or just image.jpg) in the html file. The browser will prepend file:/// on the addressbar.